# Get number in between letter and dash(-) php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains a letter, numbers and a dash (-). The numbers represent a specific month and a specific year.

(i.e. 'M4-16' -- April 2016)

I need to break out the 4 by itself and then the 16 by itself. I'm blanking on how to do this right now, so sorry for not including what I've tried.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php - Like this?

Comment: Please provide more input and expected output strings.

Comment: @StevenDropper it can be any number... 'M5-17', 'M12-20', etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the format of the relatively simple string, no regex is needed:

```
$str = "M4-16";
$parts = explode("-", $str); // Gives ["M4", "16"]
$part1 = substr($parts[0], 1); // Gives 4
$part2 = $parts[1]; // Gives 16
```